# Solving $x = 5(y^2+10y+20)$ for $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I have an equation:

$$x = 5(y^2+10y+20)$$

For context, $y$ is a value that represents the current level of a user. The equation is looking for $x$, i.e finding how much experience ($x$) is required to achieve the inputted level $y$.

My goal is to reverse this:

$$y=something ...$$

In doing so, I would be able to find the given level (y), with the inputted XP (x).

I am unsure of where to go from in order to do so. Upon trying to isolate by 'common' means (reversing actions until I can isolate), I'm left with answers that I cannot further simplify, or at least am unsure how to. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, isolate the quadratic term:
$$\frac{x}{5} = y^2 + 10y + 20$$
Then you can complete the square by adding 5 to both sides:
$$\frac{x}{5} + 5 = y^2 + 10y + 25 = (y+5)^2$$
Finally, you can take the square root and subtract 5 from both sides:
$$\pm\sqrt{\frac{x}{5} + 5} - 5 = y$$

Comment: You forgot the plus or minus sign before the square root

Comment: I did notice that, but for my use case his answer was correct, as negative 'levels' don't exist in my algorithm, though they are mathematically there :)

Answer (score 0):

$$5y^2+50y+(100-x)=0$$
solve for $y$ using the quadratic formula.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1592782)

Comment: it was an attempt to get the op to work it out for himself, but ok. i guess that it should've been a comment.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond to the question, and it's good to provide clues/hints and get the OP to work it out for themselves. I just marked your answer because another user had flagged it, and it showed up in my review queue. Generally, an answer should either answer the question, or if you're providing a hint, be fuller and provide more information. In this case, the answer seems more appropriate for the comment section. For more on how to write a good answer, see [this reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).